# return records by kNN using lon/lan in postgis

Tags: postgis

I have three columns in my Postgres table report named place, latitude and longitude and I want to get for every place all the records in a specific area (10 m) according to ST_DWidthin of the lan/lon i.e.

> place | places_in_range 
>  area1 | 20m 
>  area2 | 100m 
>  and so
>   on.

I have tried to start with something like this:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(SELECT r.latitude, r.longitude FROM report r), 10);
```

But I am new to PostGIS and don't know how to achieve this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT a.place, b.place
FROM report a, report b
where ST_DWithin(
        ST_MakePoint(a.lon, a.lat),  
        ST_MakePoint(b.lon, b.lat),
        10)
and a.place <> b.place;
```

The result is the two places in each row that they have a distance between them less than 10.

Comment: Thank you, that approaches my problem, but I want to get only three places of which are in range for example if there are 10 places nearby, I only want 3 of them not all the 10.

Comment: @Mike Can you explain more please, I didn't get what you look for? You mean you want just three places within 10? Ok! so randomly three places or the first three places or nearest three places?

Comment: Thank you, your above solution helped me to fix it myself I have nested two select operations and all works well :).